# Is it possible to store objects of different classes in Java collections?

Tags: java, collections

Is there a structure to store non-duplicated elements at a time, such as storing Line, Circle, String, Integer in one structure?
I want to know because I wrote a class and this class returns many different objects. I want to return these objects one at a time.

Comment: Use `Set<Object> x = ...;` or `ArrayList<Object> x`. It's not very clear what do you mean by "non-duplicate".

Comment: What do you mean by "non-duplicate"? Every collection is able to store any object.

Comment: Look into polymorphic collections.

Comment: Yes, but why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `nonduplicate elements` is different objects with same data? Like stringObject1 = "123" and stringObject2 = "123".

Comment: store Line line=new Line() and String string="foo" for example

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with any Collection by parameterizing it with `<Object>`

Comment: There's an asterisk with this:  if two `Object`s hash to the same value then you can't use `Set` effectively.

Comment: Also, not every collection supports non-duplicate entries.  Only sets do.

Comment: @Makoto Why shouldn't you be able to use `Set`? Duplicate hashCode might not be great, but they are valid...

Comment: @Puce: You missed my point.  Only `Set` would respect the requirement of not allowing duplicate values into it, and if you didn't override `hashCode` in an effective way per object, you'd get collisions.  Yes, it's valid, but it's buggy at best, and broken at worst.

Comment: @Makoto no. It's perfectly fine. Why do you think Object.hashCode() is so badly implemented that it would lead to many collisions? Why do you think that collisions would make the set buggy or broken? It doesn't, and not all sets use hashCode(), BTW.

Comment: @Makoto: no, hash code collisions won't make your code buggy or broken. It just might impact the performance. In worst case, a hash based Set might degenerate to a List.

Comment: @JBNizet:  If the objects placed into the collection violate the convention of `equals`; that is, two objects that are `.equal` don't have the same `hashCode`, it's a problem, and that's according to the Javadoc.  I've also yet to come across a set implementation using `Set` that didn't use `hashCode`; perhaps you could enlighten me?

Comment: @Makoto: If a class violates the hashCode contract, then you will get these issues also if you don't mix the Set with objects of other types.

Comment: @Makoto I don't think `TreeSet` uses hashCode

Comment: @Makoto I don't dispute that. But that's not what your initial comments claimed.